# Flat rate still showing after disabled

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, flat

Magento 2.1.4 : Disabled flat rate via store > configuration > sales > shipping method like this:

[image]

I have already deleted the cache, upgrade, static content deploy but it keeps showing the flat rate at checkout:

[image]

i checked the core config data, turns out there was flat rate that was still active:

[image]

but when i set the active value to zero, and cleared cache and etc, when i go to /checkout and fill address and post code ,  its not triggered to refresh the shipping method, so it said there is no shipping method available

Answer (score 0):

You can try and check:

```
rm -rf var/cache/ var/generation/ var/page_cache/ var/view_preprocessed/ 

rm -rf pub/static

php bin/magento cache:clean

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: Tried this and, it broke the site (assuming using apache) because the .htaccess in pub/static will disappear. To fix, restore the .htaccess there or only delete the frontend folder inside static.

Still had the same problem after though.